# Cropping different layers of a gif differently in Photoshop CS3

Tags: gif, crop, cs3

I have a gif of two people where one of them is moving out of the frame and I want to crop that person out of the gif entirely, leaving just the main person, which means cropping each layer slightly differently. I can crop the first layer, but it won't let me crop any more layers after that. Is this possible? And if it is possible, how do I get the layers that will be slightly different sizes now back to together so the gif works like it should?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you are not able to find the frames of the GIF image to edit them. You can simple go to `Windows->Timeline` it will show you the timeline frames of that GIF file. Though I don't have PS CS3, but it would be same in that version as well. I have also attached one screenshot to make it easier. Also to crop the image, you won't need to crop the dimensions, just select (`M` marquee tool) delete the object from the frame, it will be the best.
[image]

Thanks, Hope the answer is helpfull.

Answer (score -1):

GIFs don't have layers as such. They contain a series of images, and each image after the first isn't so much a complete image as a set of deltas ... the differences between the original image and the next.

IOW, I don't think you can do this directly, but you may be able to find software that exports the GIF to a series of individual images, do the editing you need on those, then recombine to a single GIF.

Comment: if you open a GIF on Photoshop, many times it will display as a series of layers with visibility turned on or off.